# Angular provider $get not initialized

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The following code is included in my 'app.js' file and used within my config to configurate `$navigationProvider.doSomething()`. Test1 and Test3 are alerted, but I can't get my this.$get method working (any of the Test2 alerts). In my opinion it should get called on the initialization of my page, right?

//providers.js

```
angular.module('myapp.providers', []).provider('$navigation', function() {
    var routes = {};

    function test () {
        alert(arguments);
    };

    alert('Test1');

    this.$get = ['$rootScope', '$location',
        function( $rootScope, $location) {
            $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function () {
                alert('Test2');
            });

            alert('Test2');

            return {};
        }];

    this.doSomething = function () {alert('Test3')};
});
```

//app.js

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', [
        'myapp.providers'
    ]).config(function ($locationProvider, $navigationProvider) {
        $navigationProvider.doSomething();
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

EDIT:

I was able to get it working by adding a `.run(['$navigation'], function ($navigationProvider) {})` block to my 'myapp.providers' module. So to specify my question a little bit more, why is there no automatic initialization happening (since I'm configuring the provider in app.js)? Is there any other solution to get my provider initialized? An empty module.run()-block seems to be a little bit stupid to me!

Answer (score 0):

You're answering your own question in large part.  Configuration should happen at config time and instantiation at run time.  Otherwise what is the value of a configuration phase?